# File upload to third party API with HTTP 307 Temporary Redirect in Flask

Tags: flask, request, http-status-codes, http-redirect, http-status-code-307

I have a scenario where I have to upload a file from flask app to a third party API. I have wrapped all API requests in Flask to control API usage. For this I have redirected the traffic from main route towards the api wrapper route with http 307 status to preserve the request body and in the API wrapper I have used request to post into third party API endpoint.

The problem is only file < 100KB gets send through the redirection request, having a file larger than 100 KB gets somehow terminated in the sending phase.

*Is there any limit in the 307 redirection and payload size?*

I tried debugging by watching the network timing stack trace, from there it seems the request is dropped in the sending phase.

**Main Blueprint**

```
@main.route('/upload/',methods=['POST','GET'])  
def upload(): 
    #for ajax call
    if request.method == 'POST'
        return redirect(url_for('api.file_push'),code=307)
    else:
        return render_template('file-upload.html')
```

**API Blueprint**

```
@api.route('/upload/',methods=['POST'])
def file_push():
    upload_file = request.files['file']
    filename = urllib.parse.quote(upload_file.filename)
    toUpload = upload_file.read()
    result=requests.post(apiInterfaces.FILE_UPLOAD_INTERFACE+'/'+filename,files{'file':toUpload})
    return result
```

Yes, I can directly send post request to API endpoint from main route but I don't want to, it will destroy my system design and architecture.

Comment: would you mind to explain how it will destroy your "system design and architecture"?

Comment: I want a separate blueprint to handle all third API usages so that I could use it for mobile development.

Comment: Then don't add the upload route in the main, you already have it in API blueprint, register that blueprint with the app. Why did you introduce a hop? what was the reason to put the wrapper in main and then redirect?

Comment: I have updated the code have a look. I need main to render a template in case of GET request. For POST(from ajax) I have to carry the request payload to the API wrapper so that it would send the post request to third party API with the same request payload.

Comment: You are not getting my point. You could eliminate that route in main and have upload and render code in API blueprint itself.

Comment: Yes I could have. I can solve that problem that way. But its strange for a redirection to terminate for a large file size. I wanted to know why, how and when? It could be bug or something that I may have been missing out.

Comment: I am also experiencing this. Do you have a solution yet?

Comment: @ndtreviv No. I tried debugging, searched here and there but no luck. So opted direct use of API with no redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Python, and possibly `requests` so this answer will be based on what I've learned figuring this out (debugging with a colleague). I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6312) with `psf/requests`. There is a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43749587/1532974) which confirms my suspicions.

It seems that when you initiate a `PUT` request using `requests` (and `urllib3`), the entire request is sent before a response from the server is looked at, but some servers can send a `HTTP 307` during this time. One of two things happen:

1. the server closes the connection by sending the response, even if the client has not finished sending the entire file. In this case, the client might see a *closed connection* and you won't have a response you can use for redirect (this happens with `urllib3>1.26.10` (roughly)) but `requests` is not handling this situation correctly
2. the server sends the response and you re-upload the file to the second location (`urllib3==1.26.3` has this behavior when using `requests`). Technically, there is a bug in `urllib3` and it should have failed, but silently lets you upload...

However, it seems that if you are expecting a redirect, the most obvious solution might be to send a null byte via `PUT` first, get a valid response back for the new URL [don't follow redirects], and then use that response to do the `PUT` of the full file. With requests, it's probably something like

```
>>> import requests
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> data = BytesIO(b'\x00')
>>> response = request.put(url, data=data, allow_redirects=False)
>>> request.put(response.headers['Location'], data=fp, allow_redirects=False)
```

and at that point, you'll be ok (assuming you only expect a single redirect here).